# How do I remove this spilled paint from my driveway?

Tags: paint, cleaning

A paint pot fell out of the car when I opened the door and cracked open on the driveway. I mopped up as much as I could with kitchen towel. I poured over white spirit and scrubbed with an old tea towel. But it hasn't made much difference.

The pain is silk paint and the cleaning instructions say to clean brushes and rollers with warm soapy water.

So do I just continue scrubbing with soapy water or wait for it to dry and paint it black?

[image: paint on driveway]

Comment: Type of paint will help.  Any cleaning instructions on the paint pot?

Comment: @crip659 Updated.

Comment: Use a stiff brush with the soapy water if the paint has not dried.  If dried, then you need harsher cleaning, a steel  brush, sanding/scraping, high pressure washer.  Painting it black will just leave you with a black stain instead of a white stain.

Comment: I do think some kind of "dark gray" paint will be needed.  The driveway looks pretty porous, and there's no great way to get the paint out without also damaging the surface.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Read the paint can label for what the solvent/diluent is, don't guess.  And if it's water based, you just need great masses of water. KEEP IT WET!  Keep on scrubbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White spirit won't help at all on water-based paint. you want a lot of water & a big yard brush, &/or a high-pressure hose.
Either way, you need to get it all the way to either a collection point or down the city drainage [not ordinarily allowed, but in extremis.] It will leave a light stripe all the way if you don't heavily dilute it. If you break it down sufficiently, the residue will eventually wash away with rain.

The longer you leave it, the harder it will get. Move the car too, or that'll be the next thing you have to clean paint off.

I might also be tempted to ask the store why they didn't use safety clips on the lid, that you have to ping off with a screwdriver before it will open.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It wasn't the lid that came off. The bottom of the container cracked open.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's rather unfortunate :\

Comment: Interesting. We don't (not that I've ever seen) get those little safety clips here in the States. Yet another difference between our two countries separated by a common language. ;)

Comment: @TMcAndrew Well if the bottom of the container *split open* it was probably a plastic container, that'd make it a water-based paint most likely.

Comment: @Freeman I get them on higher end cans of paint.

Answer (score 1):

I know product recommendations are OT here ....but, I'd get a stripper such as Cistirus Strip, slather it on the paint, wait for a while, maybe 30 min or so.  Don't let it dry. Then hit it with a pressure washer.  If it doesn't all come off re-apply the Cistirus Strip and wait another 30 min and hit it again with the pressure washer. I've used it several times and it's pretty effective.  The other good thing it's environmentally friendly.

[image: l]

Comment: Orange oil is roughly equivalent to turpentine. Good for dissolving oils, probably ineffective on a water-based paint.

Comment: @keshlam   I've used it on a variety of paints and it's always worked well.

Comment: Is it wise to cover it with a plastic sheet to keep it from drying out during those 30 minutes?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I wouldn't use plastic, ....not sure if the citrisus would melt it or not, it's not that harsh, but could make a big mess.   I'd be more inclined to use a hand held sprayer and mist it every once in a while to keep it moist.   Depends upon temp of course, in AZ you'd probably have to mist it every few minutes! LOL

Comment: I use plastic sheets with much stronger paint removers than that.  But I'm using "garbage bag" plastic, which is polyethylene, also used in painter's drop cloths. Even my LPU paints and solvents don't eat through that.

Answer (score 1):

Caustic oven cleaner that contains lye will take the paint off.

Use appropriate protective gear for your eyes, skin and clothing. Old-school lye paste would be best, but if all you can find is the aerosol type, use it when there is no wind. You don't want to be breathing the mist.

Use enough oven cleaner to wet the paint surface and keep it moist for at least 30 minutes by misting with a pump spray bottle with plain water. Keep wild birds, pets and children away. Do not leave the lye patch unattended.

After about 30 minutes, use a stiff bristle brush on the end of a long pole to scrub the paint **slowly**. You don't want to be spattering and splashing lye all over the place. You should see the paint transform into tiny specks or flecks instead of a solid sheet. The flecks will wash away with water.

When you think you've done all you can with the brush, flood with lots of water using an open hose-end, not a nozzle. Avoid splashing. Continue scrubbing with the brush and a flood of water until all traces of lye have been washed away. You can test for completeness of rinsing by touching the surface with a bare finger and rubbing the wetness between your thumb and finger. If it feels slippery like soap, you're not finished rinsing.

Grass won't be harmed by the runoff as long as you dilute with plenty of water.

I've done this methodology on concrete by making my own lye paste from lye flakes, water and corn starch. It worked great and didn't harm the concrete. It looks like your surface is blacktop, so proceed at your own risk, and perhaps try a small patch before you go full bore.